# Django redirect to view for processing and then to outputView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

I'am currently working on a webapp in Django. On my submittion page ('submission.html' with 'SubmissionView'), users can submit some data and select some checkboxes. This all gets processed (this can take some time) and then a output table is shown in 'output.html' (with 'OutputView').

What I would like to get is when the form is submitted, the user gets redirected to a 'process.html' page (with 'ProcessView') where a dummy progress bar with javascript will be visible, just to let the user know how long it is going to take to process the data. When everything is processed and the results are available the user gets automatically redirected to 'output.html' where the result table will be visible.

So far I managed to redirect all the input from request.POST from the SubmissionView to the ProcessView, everything gets processed and again redirected to the OutputView. BUT! When submitting the form, it just stays on the submission.html page (with loading bar underneath the url) and when everything is process then the output is shown in output.html. The process.html page never shows.

I can't find how to first show the process.html page, in the background run the analysis (in my ProcessView) and when it's done show the output. Can anyone help please?

My SubmissionView:

```
class SubmissionView(View):


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UploadFileModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        mailform = Email()
        context = {
            "form":form,
            "mailform": mailform,
        }
        return render(request, "webtool/submission.html", context)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       form = UploadFileModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()

            #Some stuff gets done here

            request.session['toprocess'] = {
                "somevar":     somevar,
            }


            return render(request, "webtool/process.html")
```

My ProcessView:

```
class ProcessView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        #Some stuff gets done here

        return redirect(reverse('output'))
```

My Outputview:

```
class OutputView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    #some stuff gets done here

    return render(request, "webtool/output.html", context)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
class SubmissionView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UploadFileModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        mailform = Email()
        context = {
            "form":form,
            "mailform": mailform,
        }
        return render(request, "webtool/submission.html", context)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       form = UploadFileModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()

            #Some stuff gets done here

            request.session['toprocess'] = {
                "somevar":     somevar,
            }

            return redirect(reverse('process'))

class ProcessView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #This is what initializes the celery task
        result = task.delay()
        if result.ready() == False:
            return redirect(reverse('process'))
        elif result.ready() == True:
            return render(request, "webtool/output.html")
```

**ideally**

- 1) user submits form -> def post() in SubmissionView redirects the user to process.html (ProcessView)
- 2) In process.html (def get() inside ProcessView), a asynchronous task is initialized with celery to process the submitted data of the user
- 3) Meanwhile, a dummy loading bar is running in process.html
- 4) When celery task is finished, redirect user to output.html

**But**

- The problem with starting the asynch. task inside the ProcessView is that it creates an infinite loop because you always come back in the def get() function and just restart the process.
- Initializing the task inside the SubmissionView isn't possible because then you have to pass along the variable 'result' (with session) to the ProcessView and that isn't possible (that gives the following error: Object of type 'AsyncResult' is not JSON serializable)

Answer (score 0):

You're SubmissionView is not actually redirecting to your process view. It's just rendering the Process template but only running the post method in SubmissionView.

Instead, SubmissionView.post will have to use `return HttpResponseRedirect` to redirect to `reverse('process')`. That will redirect to ProcessView.

Then, when loading bar on ProcessView is done, javascript will have to redirect to OutputView (it will have to have access to input from SubmissionView

Comment: It redirects perfectly the way how you said it, but it still doesn't show the process.html page and just skips it to go straight from the submission page to my output page (while the waiting happens in the submission page). Do I need to first render my process.html page and after that do my calculations?

Comment: Post your html and java script. How is the loading happening?

Comment: I don't have any javascript yet I just have a basic html page with a title. I just want to get it first to work that he first loads the process.html page and when he's done goes to output.html. I found I should do this by using Celery and run asynchon tasks?

Comment: Ohh ok, you're using Celery. I've never used that but I can try to help. Can you post the html?

Comment: I added everything in the UPDATE :) (+ideally)

Comment: what is it exactly you want of the html? because it's just a simple form and the process.html is just a title actually so nothing really usefull here